# Pro Tools 9 Help : Film Sound

Tags: pro-tools, film-sound-design, sync, conform, re-conforming

Hi! First time here! Have a noob question here,

So I added some fx, ADR, and atmos/ambience to my friend's film in pro tools 9. (He gave me a .AAF export from AVID 6 after adding most of the sync sound files), Now he decided to make some changes to the cut. While working on his new cut, I tried resyncing the audio (by simple drag/drop/move) BUT most of it is out of sync. He says he's cut about 15 frames or so. How do I reduce the audio files according to the frames?
He's given me a log sheet as well as the timecode of every scene but I really don't know how to get the perfect sync the way it was syncing before. Please help.?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!  I recommend please running a search for "conform' or 're-conform', as this will answer your question.  There are far too many search results to link directly here on my answer, but this search will provide you everything you need to know.  in a nutshell, request a new AAF and pix cut to compare against - EDLs can work too but it a more labor-intensive process than comparing AAFs if you're in a rush.  The other search results will provide more depth as to what the process is like and what options you have.

Comment: I can request a new .aaf but then whatever volume leveling and automations I've done? That goes to waste no?

Comment: Okay I ran through a lot of search material, found loads of your posts ;)

i think i'll have to conform to conformalizer. I went through some tuts. What if I don't have the editor doesnt have the OLD edl.?

Comment: The new AAF is ONLY to compare/contrast regions and waveform phasing against.  Just a temporary guide track to show you where you need to slide things to match the new cut.  This is the down and dirty way of of conforming, but I use it often especially because when we conform for TV, I can't mess around with EDLs and hope they generate proper change lists.

Comment: If there's no old EDL, and one can't be generated (which would be bad on the editor because they should always keep track of different edit versions, or least one-two previous versions)... then the down and dirty AAF manual method is probably your only bet.

Comment: Thank you stavrosound, I guess I gotta do it the hard way.